# Difference between WPA, WPA2 and mixed mode on packets level

Tags: wireless, wpa2, wireshark, wpa2-psk

**What is the difference between wpa, wpa2 and mixed mode, particulary how 4-way handshake packets look-like for every type? Is there any good lecture about it with packets examples?**

Above question came to me because I'm working on college thesis, which involves some wireless network sniffing and I observed, that most routers send eapol packets which are marked as a wpa1, but encryption has value 2 (AES+CCMP) and in router configuration there is WPA2 standard set. So I'm really not sure if I can base on my own observation to correctly recognize standard of tested network.

Comment: Since your question is "can I answer a thesis question with my opinion?" Im inclined to saying this isn't about information security

Comment: @Purefan I don't know how you came to, that conclusion, but ok, trying to put it a little bit simplier - I'm looking for an explanation or lecture, books, maybe some documentation which introduces reader to differences between wireless network security standards to have proven reference I can base on, to be sure what type of security is really used, since data in packets doesn't match router configuration.

Comment: from this `So I'm really not sure if I can base on my own observation`. Also, I suggest you google "differences between wireless network security standards", it gave me around 45 million hits

Comment: @Purefan I googled it, I duckducked it, I binged it, articles which I found are too general, when I need strictly technical description and it would be perfect if there'll be 4-way handshake, eapol packets examples for every type, but some diagrams which would describe correct values for characteristical fileds in frame also would fit.